# Query for maximum number of comments by a user on a post

Tags: support, comments, data-explorer

Does a query exist in the Data Explorer which lets you know the maximum number of comments by a user on a question? I've not been able to find one; the closest query I was able to find was [Number of comments by a specific user depending on hour in a day](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/929124/number-of-comments-by-a-specific-user-depending-on-hour-in-a-day).

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/951966?pid=105539

Comment: That query works using post id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/951967/maximum-of-comments-by-a-user-on-a-post) lists the record holders for most comments on a post (question or answer). On your home site Chemistry, it's JD_PM with 17 comments on [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/102219/15751).

I was curious what the network-wide record was, so I checked a few other sites. [This Mathematics question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3029270/counting-logic-for-subsets-password-combination-etc-need-clarification-if-my) has 89 comments by the same user.

For reference, here is the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 PostId AS [Post Link], UserId AS [User Link], COUNT(*)
  FROM Comments
  GROUP BY PostId, UserId
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Of course, SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning. Feel free to fork the query to experiment (e.g. to filter only on questions) and don't forget to take the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).

Comment: Time to get that hat